# how to determine current location from GPS in iphone

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, xcode, ios-simulator, positioning

I needed to implement the positioning functionality in my next app. I got a few questions regarding the development. 
1) I found the tutorial and implemented the positioning thing.. but is it possible to simulate my code with iphone simulator or is it necessary to use the device for this purpose. while googling i read on some forum that 4.2 SIM supports GPS apps simulation though it will give Apple's headquarter's location every time but in my case the CLLocationManager's didFailWithError delegate gets called. any help with that!!

2) After determining the position, longitude and latitude, how to determine the exact area name and other information from it?

Thanks in advance for your invaluable time and feedbacks.

Comment: This works in the simulator, but the position will always be Apple's HQ.

Comment: @Time Machine Actually CLLocationManager will return your current location in the simulator, or whatever it can figure out from your ip address or wifi network. It's MapKit that always returns Cupertino.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CLLocationManager will in fact return the location of the network the simulator is using. It's MapKit that will think the current location is in Cupertino at Apple's headquarters. That you get two different locations from the calls often causes confusion.

You can get information about a given latitude and longitude by using the **[MKReverseGeocoder](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKReverseGeocoder_Class/Reference/Reference.html)**. It will attempt to give you a full address, but you can use whatever portion of it you'd like (just the country, or city and state/province, whatever).

Comment: Ok thanks guys.. but i think i am not clear yet.. look i don't wanna use the MAP kit because i want the user's location to be determined in the background.. while using MKReverseGeocoder you're bind to use MAP kit on the UI as far as i understand from the documentation and google..May be I am wrong correct me if I am.

Comment: isn't there any other way to get current location information from the latitude, longitude that we get in the CLLocation object

Comment: I'm sure there are other reverse geocoders available on the web, I've seen them. You'll need to look into licensing and API availability. There's no other way with an iOS framework, however.

Comment: My question is simple that can i reverse geocode without showing map on my UI...My app will be free by the way... and if i cannot do it with mapkit then is there another reversegeocode api available? some sample might help me more!! thanks anyways

Comment: Yes ofcourse u dont need to show a map to reverse geocode, all you need is the lat/long information, for which you need cllocation manager. If you dont want to use mapkit, there is google's reverse geocoding service http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding/#ReverseGeocoding.

Comment: @Veeru You absolutely do need to display a Google map if you use MKReverseGeooder, not for technical reasons but for legal licensing ones. He third paragraph in Apple's documentation, linked in my answer, makes it very clear. Not following the MapKit licensing restrictions is an easy way to get your app rejected, as shown in many posts here and around he web.

Comment: @Veeru The exact same licensing applies to the Google service you linked to: see "Usage Limits" farther up on that very page.

Comment: wow! that was news to me. I am about to submit my app which uses mkreversegeocoder, but no map. But i do have a part of the app which uses and shows a map, but the reverse geocoding is done in a different part of the app. Will that violate the license?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know how connected they insist it will be, the wording is vague enough that it's hard to say. The MKReverseGeocoder rejection I saw had no maps at all, making the violation clear.

Comment: @Mathew and @Veeru thanks guyz for your time.. good discussion indeed..So veeru did u figure out what 'll happen in your case?.. can we use the MKReverseGeocoder in that scenario??